# Powershell - How to Interrupt or put a timelimit to my command/function in my script

Tags: powershell

Here this situation : 
I have a Powerhsell script using module ShowUI.
I use this module to make Button to connect VM with RDP.
In my script I have to test computer TS service and return color + sentence.
I use this function in a "While" to test all (5) computers (that's mean to refresh 5 buttons state) :

```
function Get-VM_RDP_State { param ( [string]$var )

$RDP_State = Get-Service -ComputerName $var -Name TermService
if ( $? -eq 0 ) { 
    $Color_return = "Red"
    $State_return = "Error."
} 
elseif ( $RDP_State.Status -eq "Running" ) {
    $Color_return = "Green" 
    $State_return = "You can Connect."
} 
else { 
    $Color_return = "Orange"
    $State_return = "Wait..."
}               
return $Color_return , $State_return    

}
```

All work fine except one case (first one) : 
If one computer isn't started or is crashed, 'Get-Service' wait a loooong time before returing me an error : this make my ShowUI window crash.

I call this function in my "Window" from ShowUI

```
On_Loaded = {
    Register-PowerShellCommand -ScriptBlock {

            Get-ParentControl $VM_List_Used

            $j = 0

            While ( $VM_List_Used[0,$j] ) {

                $VM_Name_temp = $VM_List_Used[0,$j]
                $VM_IP = $VM_List_Used[1,$j]

                $VM_Circle_temp = "Circle_" + "$VM_Name_temp"
                $VM_Text_temp = "Text_" + "$VM_Name_temp"

                $result = Get-VM_RDP_State($VM_IP_temp)

                $Circle_Color = $Window | Get-ChildControl $VM_Circle_temp
                $Circle_Color.Fill = $result[0]    
                $Text_Content = $Window | Get-ChildControl $VM_Text_temp
                $Text_Content.text = $result[1] 

                $j++
           }        
    }            
} -Run -In "0:0:2.0"
```

How can I write somewhere in my script I don't want wait more than few milliseconds to have a reply from get-service (or any other solution!)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant way, but this should work:

```
function Get-VM_RDP_State {
  param ([string]$var)
  $job = Start-Job {Get-Service -ComputerName $var -Name TermService}
  Wait-Job $job -Timeout .005 # Or whatever amount of time in seconds you want to wait
  if ($job.state -ne 'Completed') {
    Remove-Job $job -Force
    return 'Red', 'Error.'
  } else {
    $RDP_State = Receive-Job $job
    if ( $RDP_State.Status -eq "Running" ) {
      return 'Green', 'You can connect.'
    } else {
      return 'Orange','Wait...'
    }
  }
}
```

BTW, nothing prevents you from having multiple **return** statements (it exist the first time a return statement is encountered), so you're over-complicating your code by assigning the parts of your return expression to variables and calling **return** at the end with those variables. But you can change that back if you're determined to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your usefull reply,

For informations : I had to change 1-2 things in your code.

First : **$job = Start-Job {Get-Service -ComputerName $var -Name TermService}**  don't work. After search, I have to use a scriptblock :

```
**$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-Service -ComputerName $args[0] -Name spooler } -ArgumentList $var**
```

Second thing, If the job status is Completed, when i use my return after function, return[0] is always  the job status, but not in case I stop it, that's why I had to use :

```
stop-job -Job $job -PassThru
```

With this, stop-job send me a return too and I had to just use result[1] & result[2] for my Color & Test.

My current code :

```
function Get-VM_RDP_State {  param ([string]$var)

    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-Service -ComputerName $args[0] -Name TermService } -ArgumentList $var
    Wait-Job $job -Timeout 0.6 
    if ( $job.state -ne 'Completed' ) {        
        stop-job -Job $job -PassThru
        remove-Job -job $job -Force
        $Color_return = "Red"
        $State_return = "Error."
    } 
    else {
        $RDP_State = Receive-Job -job $job
        if ( $RDP_State.Status -eq "Running" ) {     
            $Color_return = "Green" 
            $State_return = "You can connect."
        } 
        else {
            $Color_return = "Orange"
            $State_return = "Wait..."
        }
    }
    return $Color_return , $State_return
}
```

My last issue : With the Wait-job -Timeout 0.6, all is perfect : after 0.6second, Job completed or not, the code continue. But if the computer don't reply (**job.state -ne 'Completed'**) the **stop-job -Job $job -PassThru** make **50s** to stop the job :(

I don't find any solution :/

Anyone have an idea ?